# Recommendations for Numerical Analysis book covering specific requirements?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, interpolation

I have a numerical analysis course, Course content is as follows can anyone recommend me a good book or several books which covers these areas. If the book gives an intuitive idea it would be better.

**Solving system of linear equations**

- Direct Methods

• Algebraic Process
• Gaussian Elimination
• Gauss-Jordan Elimination
• Matrix-Factorization (Triangularization)

- Iterative Methods

• Gauss-Jacobi Method
• Gauss-Seidel Method
• Convergence of Relaxation

**Interpolation Methods**

•Linear Interpolation
•Newton’s Divided Difference Formula
(Polynomial Approximations)
•Newton’s Forward Difference Interpolation
•Cubic Spline Interpolation

**Solving ODE**

•Method of Starting the solution
(Taylor (power) series approach)
•Picard’s Method of Successive Approximations
•Euler’s Method
•Improved Euler’s Method
•Modified Euler’s Method
•Runge-KuttaMethod
•Predictor-Corrector Method

Comment: Store and Bulirsch is another good book to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Numerical Analysis* by Richard L. Burden and J. Douglas Faires covers all the topics you have mentioned and it's a good book with proper explanations.